# Creating two resources at once with a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say you have a Post model that has a `:title`, `:author`, `:content`, etc. It also has a `:thread_id` attribute, and it `belongs_to :thread`.

The thread model doesn't have any custom fields. The only ones you'll be needing are those created by default such as `:id`, `:created_at`, and `:updated_at`. Threads `have_many :posts`.

How do you create a form for a Thread that simultaneously creates both a Thread and a Post?

---

Related questions, possibly:

- Should I say `<% form_for @new_thread ... %>` or `<% form_for @new_post ... %>`?
- Should the form be in the Thread view code or the Post view code?

Thanks for your help, I am new to Rails and I'm still learning how to organize my code in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and the accepts_nested_attributes_for method.